# Android app memory leak

Tags: java, android, memory, android-studio, crash

I am making an app and it was almost done. Until the app kept freezing, due to memory leaking, or something. Does anyone has a fix for this? Oh yeah, it occured after adding a countdown timer. Here is some of my code: '

```
 while(methodCounter<1){ new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
//methodcounter is the amount of times the method is called
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    Timer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlertDialogClass.class));
                }

            }.start();
            }`
```

And here is some of my logcat:

```
12-22 11:31:03.096 7109-7109/com.liammertensbe.com.typefaster D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3040K (77707), 39% free 4952K/8048K, paused 27ms, total 28ms
12-22 11:31:03.444 7109-7109/com.liammertensbe.com.typefaster D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3040K (77707), 39% free 4952K/8048K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
12-22 11:31:03.791 7109-7109/com.liammertensbe.com.typefaster D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3040K (77705), 39% free 4952K/8048K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
12-22 11:31:04.140 7109-7109/com.liammertensbe.com.typefaster D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3040K (77707), 39% free 4952K/8048K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
```

Comment: Where do you increase methodCounter?

Comment: In a method called check()

Comment: where is check() getting called?

Comment: In an ontextChangedListener

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you are not trying to decrement the **methodCounter** variable. So the loop goes infinite. And that is why that your app is freezing.

Besides that you should also write the code in try and catch block and handle **OutOfMemoryError**.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i just solved my problem, i removed the loop and used a boolean instead, to check whether the method was already call, but again, thanks for your answer.